# Using JQuery in Jade conditional not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pug

In the following Jade code, using JQuery in the conditional statement does not work. Though if I were to put a `script. console.log($(document).width())` near the top of the code, it would display, which shows that JQuery is functioning properly. The `if rows.length > 0` does work.

```
block content

    div.issueContainer.ics

        if rows.length > 0

            if ($(document).width() < 1000)
                p Mobile

            else
                p Not Mobile
                //- each val in rows
                //-     +createIssueBox(val)
                //- div.addMore
                //-     h1 You can be the voice of change
                //-     div.multButtons
                //-         a(href="/issues/submit").submit-button.first Submit an Issue
        else
            div.addMore
                h1 There are no issues currently
                a(href="/issues/submit").submit-button Submit an Issue
```

Comment: Jade should create the template (being a template engine and all) while the JS modifies the template client-side. IE: `div.issueContainer.ics` could be templated as an empty div, and JS used to fill the div, based rows length and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is a client side framework, it can't operate on the server side, where the templating engine (Jade in your case) is running.

The reason `console.log($(document).width())` would work is that it is inside a client side script generated by your template.

Comment: Makes sense. Just didn't click in my head that js in jade conditionals ran server side. Thanks. I guess I'll just use pure js to find the screen width.

Comment: Welp, just realized that probably wouldn't work either since it is server side... Guess I'll just have to figure out a different way to handle mobile devices.